# build error related to g++ -c flag

Tags: eclipse, build, g++

I dont understand g++ -c flag . based on definition:Compile or assemble the source files, but do not link. The linking stage simply is not done. The ultimate output is in the form of an object file for each source file. I need help to understand what cause the error for following build process.
Thanks

i try to compile sample helloworld program in eclipse.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```

without -c. eclipse gives me error:

```
make all 
Building file: ../app.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC -MMD -MP -MF"app.d" -MT"app.d" -o "app.o" "../app.cpp"
Finished building: ../app.cpp

Building target: app.so
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -shared -o "app.so"  ./app.o   
./app.o: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.3/../../../../lib64/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
./app.o: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.3/../../../../lib64/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.3/crtendS.o:(.dtors+0x0): multiple definition of `__DTOR_END__'
./app.o:(.dtors+0x8): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: warning: Cannot create .eh_frame_hdr section, --eh-frame-hdr ignored.
/usr/bin/ld: error in ./app.o(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [app.so] Error 1

11:25:49 Build Finished (took 463ms)
```

with -c , it build fine:

```
11:33:16 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project app ****
make all 
Building file: ../app.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC -MMD -MP -MF"app.d" -MT"app.d" -o "app.o" "../app.cpp"
Finished building: ../app.cpp

Building target: app.so
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -shared -o "app.so"  ./app.o   
Finished building target: app.so
```

11:33:16 Build Finished (took 311ms)

new fix to generate a executable file

```
13:32:44 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project app ****
make all 
Building file: ../app.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC -MMD -MP -MF"app.d" -MT"app.d" -o "app.o" "../app.cpp"
Finished building: ../app.cpp

Building target: app
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -shared -o "app"  ./app.o   
Finished building target: app
```

Comment: As a side node, a shared library should not contain a main() function. You will normally create a main() function in your application, and link in libraries for other things.

Comment: Oop, i just found i set it on shared library mode by accidentally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first case, without -c, your first g++ invocation generates a fully linked executable misleadingly named "app.o". (Try typing "file ./app.o" to describe the file in both cases. That might be interesting.) You will be able to run it. (Type ./app.o)

With the -c flag, that g++ invocation just generates the object code and that *is* suitable for a further link stage (as you observe).

Comment: I fixed this app.o to executable app file. thanks but  I still dont understand why we can't compile without -c flag.

Comment: I recommend that you read something like this: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~beechung/ref/gcc-intro.html

Comment: I found this is something wrong on Eclipse.  I can compile the program fine using the Makefile under command line.  if i didnt type -c , the program gives me object file only which is matched the definition on the g++ manual. in eclipse, I dont know why it didnt stop after getting object. it goes to link stage and generate error.